# block tor2web, onion.city,cab, .link etc

Tags: configuration, onion-services, security

How would i block tor2web and proxies like that from my tor hidden services? Like a nginx rule or something to make sure no one can access my tor hidden service through these services.

Comment: Not enough reputation to comment so I'll just answer: Unfortunately not all tor2web proxies use the "x-tor2web" header. Maybe [https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12233/adding-clinet-ssl-to-hidden-service](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12233/adding-clinet-ssl-to-hidden-service) can provide a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

The Tor2Web software includes an ['X-tor2web'](https://github.com/globaleaks/Tor2web/issues/11) header in all hidden service requests [1].

You should be able to configure nginx to block requests or show an error page when the request includes a 'X-tor2web' header.